# Match 2 data.frames when one value is doubled - NA occurs

Tags: r

`dat` is a data.frame with a location column called `area`.
`map` is a data.frame which contains location called `area` and `salary`.

I want to add `salary` column to the `dat` from `map` according to their's locations.

```
map <- data.frame(
  area = c(
  "MAZOWIECKIE",
  "WIELKOPOLSKIE",
  "MALOPOLSKIE",
  "LUBELSKIE",
  "SLASKIE",
  "POMORZE",
  "DOLNOSLASKIE",
  "KUJAWSKOPOMORSKIE",
  "LUBUSKIE",
  "PODKARPACKIE",
  "SWIETOKRZYSKIE"
  ), 
  salary =  c(12962, 10449, 11204, 10626, 8375, 10399, 12883, 9136, 6000, 12843, 7800)
)

dat <- data.frame(area = c("OPOLSKIE",
                    "SWIETOKRZYSKIE",
                    "KUJAWSKOPOMORSKIE",
                    "MAZOWIECKIE",
                    "POMORZE",
                    "SLASKIE",
                    "WARMINSKOMAZURSKIE",
                    "POMORZE",
                    "DOLNOSLASKIE",
                    "WIELKOPOLSKIE",
                    "LODZKIE",
                    "PODLASKIE",
                    "MALOPOLSKIE",
                    "LUBUSKIE",
                    "PODKARPACKIE",
                    "LUBELSKIE"
                    )
           )



matched <- match(map$area, dat$area)
stopifnot(all(!is.na(matched)))

dat$salary <- NA
dat$salary[matched] <- map$salary


#  why POMORZE = NA ?! 
dat[dat$area == "POMORZE",]

# the value should be doubled
map[map$area == "POMORZE",]
```

The problem is that 1 location in in `dat` is doubled. In this case I want to double also the salary for this location in `dat`.

I can rewrite `map$salary` with the mean aggreageted by `map$area` and option `is.na = F` but maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: please post this answer I want to give ya a plus. thank you.